# How to switch back to subversion trunk in intellij

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Ok, I've switched to branch, now my files are colored as blue, but how can I switch back to trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try after switch back to the trunk to "try" a commit to see which file are going to be  commit ?

Otherwise, blue means modified file, check that with your switch intellij have not change the last modified date or something like that.

If you're sur that before the switch to the branch there was no modification in your project, a checkout can do all you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the same command you used for the switch to the branch, but this time select the URL of the trunk? I don't know anything about IntelliJ, but that's how it's usually done.

Comment: It doesn't work, files are still marked as blue and there is no option there.

Answer (score 0):

Here a response that should help you:

See [1]: [How do I switch to another subversion branch in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589517/how-do-i-switch-to-another-subversion-branch-in-intellij)

Basically you need to commit, switch and then delete your branch.

Comment: I don't need to commit. I need to roll back switch operation.

Comment: I mean commit before switching :) For switching : select VCS / git (or SVN) branches / select your trunk (master ?) / checkout

Comment: I don't need to commit, I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Forget the commit. Your question is "switch back to trunk" ? switching from branch (or trunk) corresponds to the checkout action. Am I missing something in your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out new working copy from trunk, and then delete old working copy - No way anything will be marked as "modified"...

Comment: My project is huge, I can't afford checkout.